# How to set UISlider's value not to extend over UIProgressBar's progress

Tags: swift, position, uislider, uiprogressview

I have a **UISlider** and **UIProgressView** embedded together and I want to get the position of the progress tint of progress view and stop slider to slide before the progress tint. How to get the position of UIProgressView and clip the UISlider to the bound of progress on UIProgressView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead trying to use the above method, we can also obtain the same default  behaviours from **`UISlider`** by disabling the userInteraction of the slider as:

`slider_name.userInteractionEnabled = false`

We could than set the UISlider's thumb image, which will stick to the current value you assign.

```
slider_name.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "image_name"), forState: .Normal)
```